# How to flatten tuples in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm looking to flatten an RDD of tuples (using a no-op map), but I'm getting a type error:

```
val fromTuples = sc.parallelize( List((1,"a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")) )
val flattened = fromTuples.flatMap(x => x)
println(flattened.collect().toNiceString)
```

Gives

> error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : (Int, String)
>    required: TraversableOnce[?]
>
> val flattened = fromMap.flatMap(x => x)

The equivalent list of `List`s or `Array`s work fine, e.g.:

```
val fromList = sc.parallelize(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)))
val flattened = fromList.flatMap(x => x)
println(flattened.collect().toNiceString)
```

Can Scala handle this? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Lyuben's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931844/how-to-flatten-tuples-in-spark#comment72962856_42932015), this actually can be done, sneakily:

```
sc.parallelize(List(("a", 1), ("c", 2), ("e", 4))).flatMap(_.productIterator).collect()
```

All honour to him. (Though as [Brian notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42932826/5608164), this will forego type safety.)

Answer (score 11):

Tuples aren't collections. Unlike Python, where a tuple is essentially just an immutable list, a tuple in Scala is more like a class (or more like a Python `namedtuple`). You can't "flatten" a tuple, because it's a heterogeneous group of fields.

You *can* convert a tuple to something iterable by calling `.productIterator` on it, but what you get back is an `Iterable[Any]`. You can certainly flatten such a thing, but you've lost *all* compile-time type protection that way. (Most Scala programmers shudder at the thought of a collection of type `Any`.)

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a great way, but you can perserve a *little* type safety with this method:

```
val fromTuples = session.sparkContext.parallelize(List((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")))
val flattened = fromTuples.flatMap(t => Seq(t._1, t._2))
println(flattened.collect().mkString)
```

The type of flatten will be an `RDD` of whatever the parent of all the types in the tuple. Which, yes, in this case is `Any` but if the list were: `List(("1", "a"), ("2", "b"))` it would preserve the `String` type.

Answer (score 1):

```
  val fromTuples = sc.parallelize(List((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")))
  val flattened = fromTuples.flatMap(x => Array(x))
  flattened.collect()
```

The reason for your error is

> flatMap(func) Similar to map, but each input item can be mapped to 0
>   or more output items (so func should return a Seq rather than a single
>   item).

Comment: Hm, that doesn't work for me; it yields `Array((1,a), (2,b), (3,c))` rather than the desired `Array( 1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c" )`.

Comment: You want to use productIterator for tuple here. TL;DR; `sc.parallelize(List(("a", 1), ("c", 2), ("e", 4))).flatMap(_.productIterator).collect`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there isn't a great way to do this, especially with respect to type safety.

However if you just want to print out the `RDD` in a nice flat format you can just map the `RDD` and use `mkString`:

```
scala> val myRDD = sc.parallelize( List((1,"a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")) )
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[3] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> myRDD.map{case (a,b) => s"$a,$b"}.collect.mkString(",")
res0: String = 1,a,2,b,3,c
```